# Marrakesh airport to Jemmaa el-Fna

Tags: transportation, taxis, morocco, marrakech

What's the best way for a couple of European tourists to get from Marrakesh airport (RAK) to a hotel near the Jemaa el-Fna without undue hassle or expense?

The [airport website](https://www.marrakesh-airport.com/taxi.php) says the taxi fare should be MAD 70.00 but it is usual to bargain with the driver.  It also says to avoid the taxis near the terminal, that belong to an "organized gang", and instead to walk across a car park first.  This advice seems good as far as it goes but is slightly alarming as there might be more than one such gang.

Does anyone with local knowledge have any further advice about how to best locate an honest taxi driver rather than one intent on ripping us off, or a tout expecting a large tip for the "service" of finding us a taxi?

I am aware (again from the airport website) that there is a bus, but that is not ideal as the bus stop is 800 metres from the airport terminal building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now returned from my trip with first-hand information, and despite the prices quoted on the airport website and Rome2Rio, in practice as of the time of writing the taxis are charging MAD 100 (€ 10) for a ride into town - but MAD 150 if after 8 p.m. It's possible that a cheaper price might be had by walking out of the airport to the main R212 road and getting a taxi that happens to be passing, but I didn't personally try this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the taxi is the cheapest option, and surprisingly is even cheaper than the bus. You can easily book the taxi in advance. There are a few taxi companies mentioned on [this website](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Marrakech-Airport-RAK/Djemaa-el-Fna).